# ¿Qué significa la expresión regular /#zz([0-9]+)(.*)#zz/ig?

Tags: javascript, regex

Ando nuevo en esto de expresiones regulares y me topé con esta:

```
/#zz([0-9]+)(.*)#zz/ig
```

Lo que entiendo hasta ahora es que lo que se escriba entre `#zz` y `#zz` será afectado por la expresión regular.

Entiendo que eso que dice de 0-9 se refiere a un numero y el .* a una cadena de texto.

¿Puede ser? Me gustaría poder entenderla mejor.

Comment: @Diesan Estoy reetiquetando como JavaScript debido a la sintaxis de tu regex y las etiquetas en las que ya preguntaste. Si es otro el lenguaje, por favor explicitalo. Y recordá que [todas las preguntas de regex deben estar etiquetadas con el lenguaje de programación o la herramienta utilizada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La expresión regular coincide con este patrón en cualquier lugar del texto:

```
Patrón        Descripción
#zz        ≝ texto literal

([0-9]+)   ≝ grupo 1 - coincide con (y captura el texto)
  [0-9]+      una clase de caracteres que coincide con 1 dígito `[0-9]`
              repetido `+` (1 o más veces, cuanto más pueda coincidir)  
              -es decir, 1 o más dígitos.

(.*)       ≝ grupo 2 - coincide con (y captura el texto)
  .*          cualquier caracter `.` excepto saltos de línea,
              repetido `*` (0 o más veces, cuanto más pueda coincidir).

#zz        ≝ texto literal

Modificadores:
- `i` ::: ignora mayúsculas / minúsculas (coincide con `zz`, `zZ`, `ZZ`, etc).
- `g` ::: encontrar todas las coincidencias, no sólo la primera.
```

Esto quiere decir, que va a coincidir con todas las ocurrencias de un `#zz`, seguido de al menos un dígito, hasta la última ocurrencia en la misma línea de `#zz`. Además, va a capturar por separado todos los dígitos al principio, y el resto de los caracteres.

Demo:

```js
const pruebas = [
        '#zz123abc#zz',
        'texto antes #zz4#zz texto después',
        'abc #ZZ9 def ghi jkl #ZZ mno',
        'abc #ZZ8 def ghi jkl #ZZ mno pqr #zZ stu vwx',
        '#zzabc#zz',
        '#zz1#yzz',
        '#zz1 primera #zz2 línea #zz \n #zz3 segunda #zz4 línea #zz',
      ],
      tuRegex = /#zz([0-9]+)(.*)#zz/ig;

//probar cada uno de los textos
for (let prueba of pruebas) {
    console.log('TEXTO:', prueba);
    //buscar todas las coincidencias en ese texto
    let match;
    while (match = tuRegex.exec(prueba)) {
        console.log('Coincidió con:', match[0]);
        console.log(' - Dígitos:', match[1]);
        console.log(' - Resto:', match[2]);
    }
}
```

Para más información, te recomiendo ver entre los enlaces recomendados en la información de la etiqueta regex: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info